# Chrome.usb is now api for chrome app or extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

[image]

I found the api in chrome extension docs which reads the api is deprecated chrome app platform. Does this mean the api is accessible for chrome extension now? However, it seems something goes wrong when I take it as an extension api.

Answer (score 0):

There is a currently experimental API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USB